# RailsTutorial 11.2.5 Ajax call not returning success

Tags: jquery, ajax, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

In section [11.2.5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax) of the Rails 3.2 version of Railstutorial(.org), I have been unable to get all of my relationships_controller_spec.rb tests to pass, namely the "should respond with success" methods for both creating and destroying relationships. This is despite using exact duplicates (copy and paste) of the supplied code. The received message is `expected success? to return true, got false`

In case it's in some way related, my follow/unfollow buttons did not update in the web browser, but I was able to fix this by activating `= require jquery` in app/assets/javascripts/application.js (though this step doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in the tutorial text). Prior to this fix, the associated create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb actions were not being rendered.

Now the application *seems* to be working, including the ajaxified follow/unfollow buttons (they are both updating on screen and modifying relationships as expected). Nonetheless, the two mentioned rspec tests continue to fail. I've analysed the server logs but doing this hasn't given me any clues so far.

relationships_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RelationshipsController do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before { sign_in user }

  describe "creating a relationship with Ajax" do

    it "should increment the Relationship count" do
      expect do
        xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
      end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
    end

    it "should respond with success" do
      xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "destroying a relationship with Ajax" do

    before { user.follow!(other_user) }
    let(:relationship) { user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user) }

    it "should decrement the Relationship count" do
      expect do
        xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
      end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "should respond with success" do
      xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

The app repo can be found at https://github.com/spinnn/testapp

I've noted

[Button doesn't update in Ajax - Rails Tutorial 3 at §12.2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156815/button-doesnt-update-in-ajax-rails-tutorial-3-at-12-2-5)

but this discussion doesn't seem to be applicable in this case (it also relates to the Rails 3.0 rather than Rails 3.2 version of the tutorial).

I've taken the steps of restarting the web server several times as well as resetting, repopulating and re-preparing the database, without any resolution of the issue.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3p286 and Rails 3.2.8 on OS X. Any suggestions toward addressing this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you could post some code or at the least point us to your github repo of your app, that would be great.

Comment: Okay, time to be sheepish. After cloning railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed.git I found a very straight forward solution to this problem. relationships_controller.rb had been duplicated, with a copy in app/controllers/ and a (redundant) copy also in spec/controllers/ Unfortunately, the version I had been trying to debug was the redundant version, and the real version was incomplete. Facepalm. Cautionary tale, perhaps.

Comment: Could you please make the above comment into an answer and accept it for everyone's reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, time to be sheepish. After cloning railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed.git I found a very straight forward solution to this problem. relationships_controller.rb had been duplicated, with a copy in app/controllers/ and a (redundant) copy also in spec/controllers/ Unfortunately, the version I had been trying to debug was the redundant version, and the real version was incomplete. Facepalm. Cautionary tale, perhaps.